# Lightweight, from usb bootable operating system to connect any hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb

hello i want to install a bootable operating system on my usb stick to connect hard drives on any other computer. first i tried freedos. its really lightweight but my problem was i wasnt able to connect the "REAL" harddrive from my laptop and couldnt edit textfiles.. the "edit" command wont work for me. then i tried ubuntu - it works but theres a difference between the frequency i think.. i have a x86 laptop and a x64 pc.. so what is the easiest way to install a lightweight, from USB Stick bootable operating system to connect all drives on almost any computer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the x86 (32-Bit) LiveCD/USBs. 32-Bit better if you need to boot to both 32 and 64-Bit. You just won't get the 64-Bit performance improvement. Not that you'll notice. Ubuntu is very good and can access any Windows partitions (that aren't encrypted) out-of-the-box. But there are a number of others you can use. The Ubuntu USB can be configured to have some reserved storage space so your "live" session can remember some settings so each time you use the disk you can save preferences. You can then also do a full install of Ubuntu onto the host hard disk if necessary.